# Optimize stored procedure loop to improve performance

Tags: sql, oracle

Products table:

```
PID START_DATE  END_DATE    PRODUCT_SET_ID  CREATED_DATE    UPDATED_DATE    PRODUCT_NAME    COMPANY_NM  PRICE
    1   04/01/11    06/30/11    12              09/06/16        09/06/16        Apple           ABC         50
    2   04/01/10    06/30/10    12              09/06/16        09/06/16        Toothpaste      PQR         80
    3   07/01/11    09/30/11    12              09/06/16        09/06/16        Soap            DOVE        53
    4   04/01/12    06/30/12    12              09/06/16        09/06/16        TV              ONIDA       50000
```

Order table:

```
OID PID PRODUCT_ID  SEQ_ID  TYPE_ID CREATED_DATE    UPDATED_DATE    NUMBER_VALUE    TEXT_VALUE
11  1   1           1       1       09/06/16        09/06/16        5
12  1   2           1       6       09/06/16        09/06/16        50  
13  2   1           1       3       09/06/16        09/06/16        3
14  2   2           1       7       09/06/16        09/06/16        80
```

VA table:

```
Product_ID  Product_Name
1           Apple
2           Orange
3           Toothpaste
4           Soap
5           TV
6           ABC
7           PQR
8           DOVE
9           ONIDA
```

VA_IN_TB

```
TB_NM       COL_NM     PRODUCT_ID   SEQ_ID
Product_TB  Apple      1           1
Product_TB  Orange     2           1
Product_TB  Toothpaste 3           1
Product_TB  Soap       4           1
Product_TB  TV         5           1
Product_TB  ABC        6           1
Product_TB  PQR        7           1
Product_TB  DOVE       8           1
Product_TB  ONIDA      9           1
```

I also added index to products table:

```
CREATE INDEX INDX_PID ON PRODUCT_TABLE(PID);
```

Stored Procedure to generate Order table:

```
REC_COUNT:= SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT_TABLE;
Loop_CT :=( REC_COUNT/2000000) +1;

SELECT MIN(PID) INTO LOWER_LIMIT FROM PRODUCT_TABLE;
UPPER_LIMIT := LOWER_LIMIT +2000000;

FOR i in 1..LOOP_COUNT LOOP
Create Table Temp_1 Nologging as
SELECT  ORDER_SEQ.NEXTVAL OID,
        A.PID,A.PRODUCT_ID,
        A.SEQ_ID,
        A.VALUE,
        B.TYPE_ID 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  A.PID,
            A.VA_ID,
            A.SEQ_ID,
            A.VALUE,
            B.TYPE_NAME 
    FROM
        (
        select  A.PID, 
                B.PRODUCT_ID,
                B.SEQ_ID, 
                PRODUCT_NAME VALUE 
        from PRODUCT_TABLE A 
        JOIN VA_IN_TB B 
            ON REPLACE(A.PRODUCT_NAME,'''','')=REPLACE(B.COL_NM,'''','') 
            AND A.PID BETWEEN LOWER_LIMIT AND UPPER_LIMIT
        union all
        select  A.PID,
                B.PRODUCT_ID,
                B.SEQ_ID, 
                PRICE VALUE 
        from PRODUCT_TABLE A 
        JOIN VA_IN_TB B 
            ON REPLACE(A.COMPANY_N,'''','')=REPLACE(B.COL_NM,'''','')
            AND A.PID BETWEEN LOWER_LIMIT AND UPPER_LIMIT
        ) A 
    LEFT JOIN VA_TB B 
        ON A.PRODUCT_ID=B.PRODUCT_ID
    ) A 
LEFT JOIN VA_TB B 
    ON A.TYPE_NAME=B.PRODUCT_NAME

Insert INTO ORDER_TB
SELECT * FROM TEMP_1;
Commit;

DROP TABLE TEMP_1;
LOWER_LIMIT := UPPER_LIMIT + 1;
UPPER_LIMIT := UPPER_LIMIT + 2000000;


End LOOP;
```

We have 20 million records in product table and I need to generate order table based on the products table using the above stored procedure. I have tried to optimize as much as I can, but it still takes more than 8 hours to execute on Oracle Standard One. How can I optimize this code?

Comment: Is your code actually working ???

Comment: @Raj_Te - yes it works.

Comment: What does the explain plan say? There are some typos in the code that mean it may not be doing what you expect it to be doing, and I'm struggling to see the value that your loop is adding.

Comment: @GrahamNicol - because the table has more than 20M rows, if I remove loop, it just fills all my UNDO tablespace and my Oracle crashes. So, I am breaking 20M in 2000000 loops to create tables and then insert into my master table.

Comment: What's the purpose of the temporary table? Why not insert into the destination table directly?

Comment: @Codo - I have observed insert works slower than create. So, have created a temp table and then inserted in destination table.

Comment: The join on replace(...) is messy and slow. Do you have any other way of linking the VA and Product tables?

Comment: @JohnHC - should I create columns in VA and product table with replace function already applied, this way the queries work better?

Comment: My guess is that all your data files (tables, undo log, redo log) are on a single disk and the disk (probably a rotational disk) is slow to absorb the generated data. If so, all your query and PL/SQL optimization won't make a big difference.

Comment: this is strange "REPLACE(A.COMPANY_N,'''','')=REPLACE(B.COL_NM,'''','')". Your VA_IN_TB mentioned above as VA_TB doesnot have this column

Comment: @Raj_Te - oops, I didn't copy it right. Fixed the typo.

Comment: Post structure of "VA_IN_TB" as well..I was thinking you named VA_TB as VA_IN_TB ..but it seems there are 2 tables

Comment: @dang Have you tried APPEND hint? https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint
like `insert /*+ APPEND */ into ORDER_TB from select ...` It has some drawbacks, read carefully

Comment: Also VA_TB structure is not correct ,,TYPE _NAME is missing.your query will fail

Comment: You create the temp table, populate it, read from it and drop it every iteration of the loop, which is a bunch of cpu intensive operations. Move the Create and Drop outside of the loop and use the loop purely to populate the Temp table. Also move where you insert into ORDER_TB out of the loop as well.

Comment: @Raj_Te you are right, added VA_TB_IN structure.

Comment: Joining  ON REPLACE(A.COMPANY_N,'''','')=REPLACE(B.PRODUCT_NAME,'''',''),..company name with product name..Seems wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You select data into a temp table, then copy the content of the temp table into a table. Why not select the data directly into the table?

```
Insert INTO ORDER_TB
select order_seq.nextval oid
      ,a.pid
      ,a.product_id
      ,a.seq_id
      ,a.value
      ,b.type_id
  from (select a.pid
              ,a.va_id
              ,a.seq_id
              ,a.value
              ,b.type_name
          from (select a.pid
                      ,b.product_id
                      ,b.seq_id
                      ,product_name value
                  from product_table a
                  join va_in_tb b
                    on replace(a.product_name, '''', '') = replace(b.col_nm, '''', '')
                   and a.pid between lower_limit and upper_limit
                union all
                select a.pid
                      ,b.product_id
                      ,b.seq_id
                      ,price value
                  from product_table a
                  join va_in_tb b
                    on replace(a.company_n, '''', '') = replace(b.col_nm, '''', '')
                   and a.pid between lower_limit and upper_limit) a
          left join va_tb b
            on a.product_id = b.product_id) a
  left join va_tb b
    on a.type_name = b.product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below how you can use collection to achieve your goal. Reason i asked at the beginning if your code is working fine or not coz i see many errors and in any case it will not run. I haven't tested the code as I can see you posted only a part of your code and also many things are pretty not clear. My code is just to give a snippet which you can implement.

```
 Declare

    REC_COUNT number;
    Loop_CT   number;
    LOWER_LIMIT number;
    UPPER_LIMIT number;

      Cursor cur_rec (LWR_LMT number,UPR_LMT number)  is 
       /******Assuming all your joins are working fine ..However it doesnot look so from the code your posted. ***/     
       SELECT  ORDER_SEQ.NEXTVAL OID,
                     A.PID,
                     A.PRODUCT_ID,
                     A.SEQ_ID,
                     A.VALUE,
                     B.TYPE_ID 
             FROM 
                 (
                  SELECT  A.PID,
                        A.VA_ID,
                        A.SEQ_ID,
                        A.VALUE,
                        B.TYPE_NAME 
                FROM
                    (
                    select  A.PID, 
                            B.PRODUCT_ID,
                            B.SEQ_ID, 
                            PRODUCT_NAME VALUE 
                    from PRODUCT_TABLE A 
                    JOIN VA_IN_TB B 
                        ON REPLACE(A.PRODUCT_NAME,'''','')= REPLACE(B.PRODUCT_NAME,'''','')                     
                        AND A.PID BETWEEN LWR_LMT AND UPR_LMT
                    union all
                    select  A.PID,
                            B.PRODUCT_ID,
                            B.SEQ_ID, 
                            PRICE VALUE 
                    from PRODUCT_TABLE A 
                    JOIN VA_IN_TB B 
                        ON REPLACE(A.COMPANY_NM,'''','')=REPLACE(B.PRODUCT_NAME,'''','') ----Seems Not correct.
                        AND A.PID BETWEEN LWR_LMT AND UPR_LMT
                    ) A
                LEFT JOIN VA_TB B 
                    ON A.PRODUCT_ID = B.PRODUCT_ID
                ) A
              LEFT JOIN VA_TB B 
                ON A.TYPE_NAME = B.PRODUCT_NAME ;  ----Seems Not correct.

    type var is table of cur_rec%rowtype;

    var_order_tab var;


    begin

    /**Procedure will fail if you try to do anything like this**/
    ---REC_COUNT:= SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT_TABLE;

     SELECT COUNT(*)
      into  REC_COUNT
      FROM PRODUCT_TABLE;


     Loop_CT :=( REC_COUNT/2000000)+1;

     SELECT MIN(PID) 
     INTO LOWER_LIMIT 
     FROM PRODUCT_TABLE;

     UPPER_LIMIT := LOWER_LIMIT +2000000;


     Open cur_rec(LOWER_LIMIT,UPPER_LIMIT);
     loop

     fetch cur_rec bulk collect into var_order_tab limit 100;

     FORALL i IN 1 .. var_order_tab.count
           INSERT INTO ORDER_TB
          VALUES var_order_tab(i);

     commit;

     end loop;

   close cur_rec ;

     /**** You cannot create any table like this in any procedure. This is not allowed in PLSQL.
     FOR i in 1..LOOP_COUNT LOOP
     Create Table Temp_1 Nologging as
     SELECT  ORDER_SEQ.NEXTVAL OID,
            A.PID,A.PRODUCT_ID,
            A.SEQ_ID,
            A.VALUE,
            B.TYPE_ID 
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT  A.PID,
                A.VA_ID,
                A.SEQ_ID,
                A.VALUE,
                B.TYPE_NAME 
        FROM
            (
            select  A.PID, 
                    B.PRODUCT_ID,
                    B.SEQ_ID, 
                    PRODUCT_NAME VALUE 
            from PRODUCT_TABLE A 
            JOIN VA_IN_TB B 
                ON REPLACE(A.PRODUCT_NAME,'''','')=REPLACE(B.COL_NM,'''','') 
                AND A.PID BETWEEN LOWER_LIMIT AND UPPER_LIMIT
            union all
            select  A.PID,
                    B.PRODUCT_ID,
                    B.SEQ_ID, 
                    PRICE VALUE 
            from PRODUCT_TABLE A 
            JOIN VA_IN_TB B 
                ON REPLACE(A.COMPANY_N,'''','')=REPLACE(B.COL_NM,'''','')
                AND A.PID BETWEEN LOWER_LIMIT AND UPPER_LIMIT
            ) A 
        LEFT JOIN VA_TB B 
            ON A.PRODUCT_ID=B.PRODUCT_ID
        ) A 
    LEFT JOIN VA_TB B 
        ON A.TYPE_NAME=B.PRODUCT_NAME ****/

    --Insert INTO ORDER_TB
    --SELECT * FROM TEMP_1;
    --Commit;

    /****Neither executing drop command directly is permitted***/
    --DROP TABLE TEMP_1;
    LOWER_LIMIT := UPPER_LIMIT + 1;
    UPPER_LIMIT := UPPER_LIMIT + 2000000;


    --End LOOP;


    end;
```

Comment: thanks. Why do you say create or drop is not allowed in PLSQL?

Comment: Its allowed but not the way you used. You use it with Execute Immediate.